# Original text is changed after translation

Tags: flutter, dart, google-translate

I am sending an **object** from `FirstPage` to `SecondPage`. In `SecondPage` there is an option to translate `String` of the object. After translating, if I go back to `FirstPage` and then again navigate to the `SecondPage`, it shows the previously translated `String` instead of the original `String`. But I expect the original String. Here is my code:

```
class PostDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final Post post;

  PostDetailsPage({
    @required this.post,
  });

  @override
  _PostDetailsPageState createState() => _PostDetailsPageState();
}

class _PostDetailsPageState extends State<PostDetailsPage> {

  Post _post;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _post = widget.post;
  }

  // for translation
  var translatedPost = await TranslationService.translatePost(languageCode, _post);
  setState(() {
    _post = translatedPost;
  });

  // inside build()
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0),
      child: Text(_post.title),
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0),
      child: Text(_post.description),
    ),
  }
```

Here is the function for translation :

```
  static Future<Post> translatePost(
      String languageCode, Post post) async {
    var translator = GoogleTranslator();
    String title = await translator.translate(post.title, to: languageCode);
    String description =
        await translator.translate(post.description, to: languageCode);
    post.title = title;
    post.description = description;
    return post;
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the transition code between the pages?

Comment: @SanjaySharma From `FirstPage` to `SecondPage`, Its simple `Navigator.push` with the object in parameter.